How to fix Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Given component holder class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt
I have a compose screen and inside my screen, I am initialising my viewmodel. I am trying to write androidTest for this screen. And I am getting above error. How should I modify code to avoid hiltViewModel related errors? The test is failing at val viewModel: MyViewModel= hiltViewModel()
My screen code :-
@Composable
fun MyScreen(){

val viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()



//My screen content

}

MyViewModel
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(val networkService: NetworkService, val useCase: MyUsecase): 
BaseViewModel(networkService){

//Viewmodel code

}

MyScreenTest
@HiltAndroidTest
class MyScreenTest{

@get: Rule(order=0)
val hiltAndroidRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

@get: Rule(order=1)
val composeTestRule = 
createComposeRule()

@Before
fun setUp(){
hiltAndroidRule.inject()

composeTestRule.setContent{

MyScreen()

}
}
}

build.gradle.kts :-
  default config{
       testInstrumentationRunner= "com.example.CustomTestRunner" 
 }   

 //dependencies                          
  
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
 kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.47")

                 implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0")
kaptTest("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")

androidTestImplementation("com.google .dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.44")

 kaptAndroidTest("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")

CustomTestRunner
 class CustomTestRunner: AndroidJUnitRunner(){
 override fun new application(cl: ClassLoader?, name: String?, context: Context?): Application {

return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)

}
}


You either have some annotion wrong/missing, or there are some incompatabilities with your gradle dependencies. Since you share neither with us, we cannot help you with this.

I have added few more code.  Please help me to find the issue.

Please format the code, it's hardly readable. It also doesn't compile. Please provide a [mre].
